# Numpy Array2string just writing ... in string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a simple thing to do, read some vectors and write them in a file.

The vectors are 1024 dimensional.

```
 for emb in src:
            print(len(emb[0].detach().cpu().numpy()))  #--> prints 1024!
            f.write(np.array2string(emb[0].detach().cpu().numpy(), separator=', ') + " \n")
```

My file looks like this:

```
[-0.18077464, -0.02889516,  0.33970496, ..., -0.28685367,  0.00343359,
 -0.00380083] 
[-0.04554039,  0.0891239 ,  0.0457519 , ..., -0.02622034,  0.04410202,
 -0.03626832] 
[ 0.2415923 ,  0.36748591, -0.10974079, ...,  0.06169772,  0.0134424 ,
  0.01647076] 
[ 0.019123  ,  0.00409475,  0.03623311, ..., -0.13063622,  0.02434589,
  0.00400023] 
[ 0.01281842,  0.00028924,  0.03185712, ..., -0.062907  ,  0.02143336,
 -0.00206215] 
[ 0.01748654,  0.00136842, -0.01337154, ..., -0.04148545,  0.00875527,
 -0.03006736]
```

So, I just can't access my vectors, 1024 dimension is transformed to whatever 6 or 7 dimensional vector + .... :(

How can I write vectors to my file correctly?

Cheers :)

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Comment: @berkelem i am trying..hope it works..

Comment: Do you also want those brackets?  That will make reading the file more complicated.  `array2string` is doing the same thing as `str(x)` or `print(x)`.  It's the summarized output intended primarily for quick interactive views.  It's not intended saving and reloading.

Comment: @hpaulj no, it makes reading tougher...oh, so setting the flag and just doing f.write(str(x)) is okay?

Comment: If you want the common `csv` format, `np.savetxt` is good basic choice for writing a 2d array.  The result should be readable with `np.genfromtxt`.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way of writing a 2d array to a text file (so it can be read back) is with `np.savetxt`:

```
In [309]: src = np.random.rand(6,4)
In [310]: src
Out[310]: 
array([[0.78756364, 0.11385762, 0.16631052, 0.10987765],
       [0.59954504, 0.80417064, 0.22461205, 0.47827772],
       [0.10993457, 0.11650874, 0.55887911, 0.71854456],
       [0.53572426, 0.55055622, 0.25423811, 0.46038837],
       [0.05418115, 0.50696182, 0.31515915, 0.65310375],
       [0.81168653, 0.81063907, 0.95371101, 0.11875685]])
```

write:

```
In [311]: np.savetxt('test.txt', src, fmt='%10.6f',delimiter=',')
In [312]: cat test.txt
  0.787564,  0.113858,  0.166311,  0.109878
  0.599545,  0.804171,  0.224612,  0.478278
  0.109935,  0.116509,  0.558879,  0.718545
  0.535724,  0.550556,  0.254238,  0.460388
  0.054181,  0.506962,  0.315159,  0.653104
  0.811687,  0.810639,  0.953711,  0.118757
```

Test the loading:

```
In [314]: np.genfromtxt('test.txt',delimiter=',')
Out[314]: 
array([[0.787564, 0.113858, 0.166311, 0.109878],
       [0.599545, 0.804171, 0.224612, 0.478278],
       [0.109935, 0.116509, 0.558879, 0.718545],
       [0.535724, 0.550556, 0.254238, 0.460388],
       [0.054181, 0.506962, 0.315159, 0.653104],
       [0.811687, 0.810639, 0.953711, 0.118757]])
```

`savetxt` does a formatted write, row by row, roughly like:

```
In [315]: fmt = ','.join(['%10.6f']*4)
In [316]: fmt
Out[316]: '%10.6f,%10.6f,%10.6f,%10.6f'
In [317]: for row in src:
     ...:     print(fmt%tuple(row))    # f.write(...)
     ...:     
  0.787564,  0.113858,  0.166311,  0.109878
  0.599545,  0.804171,  0.224612,  0.478278
  0.109935,  0.116509,  0.558879,  0.718545
  0.535724,  0.550556,  0.254238,  0.460388
  0.054181,  0.506962,  0.315159,  0.653104
  0.811687,  0.810639,  0.953711,  0.118757
```

In fact I can wrap that in file write:

```
In [318]: with open('test1.txt','w') as f:
     ...:     for row in src:
     ...:         print(fmt%tuple(row), file=f)
     ...:     
In [319]: cat test1.txt
  0.787564,  0.113858,  0.166311,  0.109878
  0.599545,  0.804171,  0.224612,  0.478278
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The vectors are still 1024 dimensional, but the display is only showing a curtailed view of the array.

You can view the whole array by setting print options:

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)
```

Comment: threshold=numpy.nan or threshold=np.nan...any difference ?

Comment: That was a typo sorry. If you `import numpy as np` you should use `np` throughout. If you just `import numpy` then use `numpy`. They are exactly equivalent, so just a matter of preference.